# Docker build fails on RUN pip install -e git <repo url>

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker image.

```
This is my docker file
FROM python:3.6
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y gcc libc-dev g++ libffi-dev libxml2 libffi-dev unixodbc-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install numpy
RUN pip install -e git+<git repo>
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But the RUN pip install -e git+ fails. I tweaked my dns setting in the docker.service file, but still no luck.

Comment: Fails with what error message?

Answer (score 1):

The `-e` flag gives me an error when I try it with a GitHub repo. Perhaps you are running into [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2344)?

Using `requests` as an example:

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/requests/requests.git
```

The error I see on my end is:

> Could not detect requirement name for 'git+git://github.com/requests/requests.git', please specify one with#egg=your_package_name

To fix it, I added the name of the package that I'm installing:

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/requests/requests.git#egg=requests
```